# Chromecast Failed to play hls encrypted custom asset

Tags: chromecast

CustomReceiverApplication : **CastReferencePlayer-master** (github)

SenderApplication : **CastVideosSample** (github)

With the above applications chrome cast is able to play un-encrypted custom asset, but failed to play encrypted asset.

Modification in CastReferencePlayer-master::player.js

below lines are added.

```
host.licenseUrl = "http://192.168.6.135/mpeg/key123";
host.updateSegmentRequestInfo = function (requestInfo) 
{
requestInfo.withCredentials = true;
requestInfo.headers = {};
requestInfo.headers['origin'] = info.message.media.customData.origin;
requestInfo.headers['content-type'] = info.message.media.contentType;
requestInfo.headers['accept-encoding'] = 'gzip';
}
```

Errors from chrome-cast debug log.

**Refused to set unsafe header "origin"
Refused to set unsafe header "accept-encoding"**

Please find below link to download the logfile.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1Nd3ciEQ3CIeGdVM2FsYVNGWk0

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](http://www.anarchy46.net/2012/06/refused-to-set-unsafe-header.html), usually it appears only in Webkit based browsers. Basically a browser like Google Chrome will not change certain `http` headers in an XMLHttpRequest using `setRequestHeader()`. Make sure you check your sources before you use things like external scripts. Try to set the header to `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length`.